# Un-auto-complete Terminal

Tags: command-line, 14.04, shortcut-keys

In the terminal, one can use the tab key to help auto-complete typing out a directory or file name. However, if I make a mistake and mistype the beginning of the directory and "tab it out", I end up having to use backspace and re-type it in. Is there a shortcut key to undo the auto-completion in the terminal?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

To expand on what I've said in a comment, I was wondering if there was a shortcut to undo to the last directory. So, currently ctrl+shift+- seems to work well except it un-does individual letters.

For example, if I have the following directory setup:

```
Documents

 --> d1something

 --> d2something
```

And I want to go to "d2something" but accidentally type "cd d1", it will autofill to:

```
cd Documents/d1something/
```

Then, by using ctrl+shift+- it will then be:

```
cd Documents/d1something
```

Again:

```
cd Documents/d1
```

Again:

```
cd Documents
```

What I was wondering if there's a shortcut to get from `cd Documents/d1something/` back to `cd Documents` (first and last step). If not, the ctrl+shift+- will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can provide another answer for what you are trying to do here, but it is not really "undo", what you want is "pop the last directory name". The undo function is undoing what tab completion added, which was the "something" suffix. You typed "d1", so that's a separate undo step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [bash man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html), the default shortcut for the `undo` function is either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (note that this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> on most keyboards) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>. If your tab completion added a trailing slash to the directory name, you may have to undo twice, once to remove the slash and once more to remove the text that the completion added.

If instead what you want is to remove the last complete directory component from a path you are entering in bash, the closest way to achieve this is with the `backward-kill-word` function. By default this is bound to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> key combination. This will erase the last "word" from your command line, where a word consists entirely of alphanumeric characters.

This seems to work with your given example directory names. Note that if the last directory name contains spaces or punctuation characters like `-` or `_`, these are treated as word delimiters, so you may have to repeat this key combination more than once to erase back to the last `/` character.

Comment: ctrl+_ makes my terminal smaller. ctrl+x just moves the cursor to the beginning/end of the line (back and forth). ctrl+u removes the whole line, making me start over again.

Comment: @DanW Are you sure you're using Ctrl+_ (meaning Ctrl+Shift+-)? Doing Ctrl-x twice in a row should move to the beginning/and of the line like you are describing, but not once. I meant Ctrl-x then Ctrl-u as one sequence.

Comment: Sorry, was not using shift and that ends up like I described as a comment to the other answer - http://askubuntu.com/a/465480/204995. And it appears the sequence ctrl+x, ctrl+u will mimic the behavior of ctrl+shift+_ when done multiple times.

Comment: @DanW Good, that's expected. Can you clarify in your question what you are expecting the undo function to do beyond what you are seeing from these key sequences? Maybe show an example set of directories and describe what you want completion and undo to do for you?

Comment: I've updated my question for clarification. If nothing like what I tried to explain exists, ctrl+shift+- will work fine.

Comment: Notice that *you* need the shift because your keyboard has the underscore "_" under shift. The command is Ctrl+underscore, however your keyboard generates the underscore...

Answer (score 2):

Use Zsh, with oh-my-zsh (optional)

press control and c or if you want maybe a better way, press control + shift + underscore key. Sorry I don't use bash, zsh is superior anyway, give it a try

Comment: ctrl+shift+_ does an undo of the auto-complete and then an undo of what I've typed and seems to be pretty close to what I'm looking for. However, is there something that will automatically take me to the previous directory? With the ctrl+shift+_ I have to hit that once, then backspace the incorrect letter and again tab out.